# How to select only those records which are present in given all DATE range

Tags: mysql, sql

I wanted to select only data which are present for all date with repeated data count.

Example My table data is :

| user_id | row_created |
| --- | --- |
| 8SRWS3hMR | 2020-12-14 00:13:31 |
| 8SRWS3hMR | 2020-12-14 00:35:06 |
| 8SRWS3hMR | 2020-12-14 12:11:37 |
| 8SRWS3hMR | 2020-12-14 13:16:27 |
| 8SRWS3hMR | 2020-12-14 16:30:00 |
| 8SRWS3hMR | 2020-12-14 19:25:11 |
| 8SRWS3hMR | 2020-12-14 19:27:07 |
| 8SRWS3hMR | 2020-12-15 17:14:06 |
| 8SRWS3hMR | 2020-12-16 14:53:54 |

And if I select the date range between `2020-12-14` to `2020-12-17` then the output should be null.

And if I select the date range between `2020-12-14` to `2020-12-16` then the output should be below

| user_id | total | row_created |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 8SRWS3hMR | 7 | 2020-12-14 00:13:31 |
| 8SRWS3hMR | 1 | 2020-12-15 17:14:06 |
| 8SRWS3hMR | 1 | 2020-12-16 14:53:54 |

I had tried the below query

```
select user_id, count(user_id) as total, row_created from reward
where user_id = '8SRWS3hMR' AND DATE(row_created) BETWEEN '2020-12-14' AND '2020-12-17'
group by DATE(row_created);
```

But as per my requirement, the output should come null because in `BETWEEN` date range I have pass `'2020-12-17'`.

Please ignore the grammar mistakes.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `HAVING` clause as follows:

```
SELECT USER_ID,
       COUNT(USER_ID) AS TOTAL,
       ROW_CREATED
  FROM REWARD
 WHERE USER_ID = '8SRWS3hMR'
   AND DATE(ROW_CREATED) BETWEEN '2020-12-14' AND '2020-12-17'
 GROUP BY DATE(ROW_CREATED) 
 HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT DATE(ROW_CREATED)) = datediff('2020-12-17', '2020-12-14') + 1;
```

**--UPDATE**

```
SELECT * FROM
(SELECT USER_ID,
       COUNT(USER_ID) AS TOTAL,
       ROW_CREATED,
       COUNT(DISTINCT DATE(ROW_CREATED)) OVER (PARTITION BY USER_ID) AS CNT
  FROM REWARD
 WHERE USER_ID = '8SRWS3hMR'
   AND DATE(ROW_CREATED) BETWEEN '2020-12-14' AND '2020-12-17'
 GROUP BY USER_ID, DATE(ROW_CREATED) 
) T WHERE CNT = datediff('2020-12-17', '2020-12-14') + 1
```

Comment: It's not worked. Even I passed the date from 14 to 16 then also, I am not getting any response. It should come if I passed the date between 14 to 16. It's only will not come in case I passed 17 because the record for 17 for any user is not available.

Comment: I think the idea is clear right? Please try to play with this logic. Else I will take care of it but once after you play with it

Comment: I play but not getting the expected output.

Comment: What is the result if you remove having clause?

Comment: If remove the having clause I am getting the result for date 14/15/16.

Comment: Thank's @Popeye I have used the previous query as suggested by you. First, I query to select eligible users. Second, select the eligible user transaction count. This way I am able to solve my query.  I have used the below query.

Comment: SELECT COUNT((user_id)),  user_id AS user_id FROM reward WHERE DATE(row_created) BETWEEN '2020-12-14' AND '2020-12-16' GROUP BY user_id, DATE(row_created) HAVING COUNT(*) = datediff('2020-12-16', '2020-12-14')+1;

Answer (score 0):

This is a little complicated, because you want the summary by date.  You can use window functions:

```
SELECT r.*
FROM (SELECT USER_ID, DATE(ROW_CREATED) as date, COUNT(*) AS TOTAL,
             MIN(ROW_CREATED) as ROW_CREATED,
             COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY USER_ID) as num_days,
             DATEDIFF(x.end_date, x.start_date) + 1 AS total_days
      FROM REWARD R CROSS JOIN
           (SELECT DATE('2020-12-14') as START_DATE, DATE('2020-12-17') as END_DATE
           ) params
      WHERE USER_ID = '8SRWS3hMR' AND
            ROW_CREATED >= x.start_date AND
            ROW_CREATE <= x.end_date + interval 1 day
      GROUP BY DATE(ROW_CREATED) 
     ) R
WHERE num_days = total_days;
```

The subquery summarizes by day.  It includes two counts:

- The number of distinct days for the `USER_ID`.
- The total number of days.

To avoid entering the same dates more than once, these are defined in a subquery.  Also note that the date comparisons are re-arranged.  Instead of using the `DATE()` function, inequalities are used.  This makes the expression more compatible with indexes.

Answer (score 0):

select user_id, count(user_id) as total, row_created from reward
where user_id = '8SRWS3hMR' AND DATE(row_created) >=  '2020-12-14' AND DATE(row_created) <= '2020-12-17'
group by DATE(row_created)
having count(user_id) >= DATEDIFF( row_created, '2020-12-17')

Comment: Siva, Your query is not working for me. I want the user if the record for a particular user exists every day. Like if records are available for every day from 14 to 17  then only that user will come in output. If he missed any day then it should not come in output.